# Where and how do you import node modules?

Tags: node.js, pixi.js

So I've used Pixi JS as a standalone file for quite sometime now, but I wanted to learn how to use it in Node. The trouble is, I have no idea how to actually import it.

Some clarification:

- I'm using Pug to create my webpage, importing a main.js script that will contain base Pixi JS code
- I've managed to get my app.js up and running, and can serve my index.pug file

While reading up on how to start a Pixi app with Node JS, I saw that you're supposed to import like

`import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';`

But I always get a 404 this way when importing directly in my main.js file. Where am I actually supposed to import?

Comment: You need to install the using `npm install pixi.js` then import it where (.js file) you use it.

Comment: @TheAlpha Probably should have clarified further; I've done that. The import, when done as suggested (in the main.js file) says it failed to resolve the module, suggesting that the path is incorrect.

When given an absolute path, then it comes up with a 404.

Comment: A 404? That doesn't make any sense--an import isn't an HTTP request unless it's explicitly in the browser. What *exactly* are you doing? There isn't much context anyone can use to help. How are you packaging your script(s)? Are you *not* packaging your scripts? If not, then that's why.